# What is the SCIFI book about some species of moon beings and their interactions and it could be allegorical to modern race and ethnic relations?

Tags: story-identification, books

There was a small  (150 pg paper back) book I read 20+ years ago in an college anthropology class.   I think the anthropology class was about race & ethnic relations and this book was some reading assignment I had.

The story line had something to do with some people going to moon and encountering different species of moon beings.    Each species was distinct and somewhat separate but never had conflicts with each other and even cooperated by using distinct abilities of each species.

I vaguely recall that the main human character(s) may have actually been a stow-away on the moon mission and there may have been a murder of either some of the moon beings or some of the human characters in book.

What is this book?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like Jules Verne's *The First Men In The Moon*. Or possibly CS Lewis's *Out Of The Silent Planet*, although that was Mars rather than the Moon.

Comment: I took me a while -- but I found my copy -- It was Out of the Silent Planet -- maybe not stowaways but a kid-napping.   And not really the moon either.    Thanks!!!

Comment: **The First Men in the Moon** is by H.G.Wells.  Verne wrote **From the Earth to the Moon** and **Around the Moon**