# Novel in which space traveler finds planets in various states of Biblical progression, i.e. Creation, The Fall, The End Times

Tags: story-identification, novel, christian

I remember reading, or at least starting, a novel probably 25 years ago where the protagonist is in a spaceship travelling to different planets where each one was experiencing different Biblical progression.  That is, one planet had already undergone the End Time whereas another had just been Created - and so on and so forth.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60633/book-about-water-world-with-islands-that-moved-with-the-waves-and-tides and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31273/what-is-the-scifi-book-about-some-species-of-moon-beings-and-their-interactions (about the first and second books in the trilogy)

Answer (score 14):

This sounds like it could be C. S. Lewis's [*Space Trilogy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Space_Trilogy):

- [*Out of the Silent Planet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_the_Silent_Planet)
- [*Perelandra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perelandra)
- [*That Hideous Strength*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/That_Hideous_Strength)

The stories take place on Malacandra (Mars), Perelandra (Venus) and Earth, respectively.

It's been a long time since I read these, but (with a refresher from Wikipedia [link above]), I believe that the first book discusses Earth's Fall; the second takes place on Perelandra, which is in a "Garden of Eden" state, and the third, on Earth, would correspond to the end times. I may have the first and last transposed (but I don't think so).

In the first book, *Out of the Silent Planet*, a spaceship is used to travel to Mars. I'd be hard-pressed to call his [means of transport to Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perelandra#Plot_summary) a spaceship, exactly, but he does travel through space to get there. In the third book, of course, no space travel is needed - everything happens here on Earth.

Comment: "Ransom is transported in a casket-like vessel seemingly made of ice, which contains only himself. He gets Lewis to blindfold him so the sunlight will not blind him once he travels beyond the earth's atmosphere. He does not wear any clothes on the journey as Oyarsa tells him clothes are unnecessary on Venus. He returns to Earth over a year later and is met by Lewis and another friend." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perelandra

Comment: I believe Lewis once commented that when he wrote the first one he went into great detail about the spaceship. By the second one he knew that didn't matter, so he just had him carried by an angel.

Comment: I appreciate the responses.  I have read the first and most of the second of the Lewis space trilogy.  It's not those books that I'm trying to find.

Comment: As a note, the spaceship is also used to travel to Venus separately.